# NGRX reducers factory doesn't work on production

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have problem with ngrx on production build. I reproduct problem on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-reducer-factory-production-fail?file=app%2Freducer.ts). It works for development build but when I try to run it after production build it doesn't work.
[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGcbB.gif)

Any ideas How to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Minification changes property names

Comment: oo :( Do you know any way to solve this problem ?